# Use of multiple multicolumn in one row

Tags: multicol

I'm trying to create multiple framed cells with colored backgrounds in one row of a table using multiple multicolumns in each row. I want the colored areas to have the same size (width) (3cm). But somehow it doesnt seem to work, to generate these identical, colored, multicolumn cells in one row.

merci A

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{Grey}{HTML}{808080}%define a color for tables - hex # gray

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}%
{
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}
p{4cm}%
p{3cm}%
p{4cm}%
p{3cm}%
}
 &\\  \cline{2-2}  \cline{4-4} 
\textbf{Erstkontakt (Datum)}   &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Grey}}   &
\textbf{Projektnummer}   &   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Grey}} \\ [6pt] \cline{2-2}  \cline{4-4} 
 \end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. from mwe follows that you have `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{Grey}}`. the same you obtain without `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 1):

your question is still not clear ... i suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout, as you see, your table is wider than text width)

mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}       % <-- not used
\usepackage{multirow}       % <-- changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % <-- changed

\definecolor{Grey}{HTML}{808080}%define a color for tables - hex # gray

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}%
{
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4cm}%
        >{\columncolor{Grey}}p{3cm}%
                             p{4cm}%
        >{\columncolor{Grey}}p{3cm}%
}
\textbf{Erstkontakt (Datum)}   &    &   \textbf{Projektnummer}   &      \\
```

in so dark gray cell color the border lines has not sense.

in the case, that your table has more rows and only one has colored cell, than you can simple write:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}       % <-- not used
\usepackage{multirow}       % <-- changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % <-- changed

\definecolor{Grey}{HTML}{808080}%define a color for tables - hex # gray

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}%
{
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                             p{3cm}
                             p{4cm}
                             p{3cm}
}
\textbf{Erstkontakt (Datum)}   
    &   \cellcolor{Grey}   
        &   \textbf{Projektnummer}   
            &   \cellcolor{Grey}         \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{Grey}{HTML}{808080}%define a color for tables - hex # gray

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}%
{
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}
p{4cm}%
p{3cm}%
p{4cm}%
p{3cm}%
}
 &\\  \cline{2-2}  \cline{4-4} 
\textbf{Erstkontakt (Datum)}   &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Grey}}   &
\textbf{Projektnummer}   &   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Grey}} \\ [6pt] \cline{2-2}  \cline{4-4} 
&&&\\
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: code in your is the same as in the question. what was the problem? what you solve?

Comment: No, if you look closely, I forgot the &&& \\ before the end{tabular}.my goal was to create something like a text input field.therefore I built a table with 4 columns where the 1column holds the name for the input field, the second the input field itself, the third the second name and the 4th the second input field. Without the &&&\\ the input fields don’t appear...

Comment: this only introduce new empty row. this was not asked in your question nor solve anything in your question. if you are not willing to clarify your question, than is better to delete it.

Comment: I adjusted the question...

Comment: I adjusted the question again...